# Scroll to Top of the screen not working from Link in Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I can't make this scrolling with animation working from my simple component, and I would like to understand why!

Basically this is my simple code:

```
(function(angular) {
  var app = angular.module('pi.core');
  app.directive('piGoUp', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        classes: '@',
        image: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (!scope.image) scope.image = 'go-up.svg';

        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250) {
              $('#scrollup').fadeIn(300);
            } else {
              $('#scrollup').fadeOut(300);
            }
          });

          $('.pi-go-up').click(function() {
            console.log('ciao');
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
            return false;
          });
        });
      },
      template:
        '<div class="pi-go-up {{classes}}"><div class="pi-go-up-text" ng-transclude></div><div><img src="{{image}}"/></div></div>'
    };
  });
})(angular);
```

With the CSS, in case it's relevant for the missing behaviour:

```
.pi-go-up {
  display: inline-flex;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.pi-go-up-text {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.38;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
  color: #575757;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
.pi-go-up img {
  width: auto;
  height: 36px;
  margin-left: 11px;
}
```

I am following this [guide](http://redvinestudio.com/how-to-add-a-scroll-to-top-link-to-your-website/) with a working demo.

Any idea about how I can make it working? I tried in several ways, but I would like to keep it inside the directive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working Solution, (You had some implementation error):

```js
(function(angular) {
  var app = angular.module('app', []);
  app.controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
  });
  app.directive('piGoUp', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        classes: '@',
        image: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (!scope.image) scope.image = 'go-up.svg';

        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250) {
              $('#scrollup').fadeIn(300);
            } else {
              $('#scrollup').fadeOut(300);
            }
          });

          $('.pi-go-up-text').click(function() {
            
            $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: 0
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          });
        });
      },
      template: '<div class="{{classes}}"><button class="pi-go-up-text" >GoUp</button>'
    };
  });
})(angular);
```

```css
.pi-go-up-text {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="DemoController" style="height:2000px;overflow-y:scroll;">
    <span pi-go-up />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav! First of all thanks for answering! For me it is still not working, I copied your code changing the class name to go up to the top of the page/body/screen when I press on my template directive...the function on click event is triggered, but the page doesn't move...

Comment: all your code, just moved the controller instruction to first in the directive controller, then tried also in the one outside the directive.. the style overflow is the same in my body and checked the div containing the directive too...except the position: fixed;, if I apply it then my directive disappear behind the footer... that's very important I guess..

Comment: you have to just copy all directive code,  and just put "pi-go-up" as attribute on the link on which you want to add the scroll to top functionality.

Comment: Not clear to me sorry, I added a ng-click on the image. When I press the image there is the click event that executes the scrolling functionality...